# How to Export Data from AWS Elasticsearch Domain into a CSV File

Tags: amazon-elasticsearch

I would like to know how to export indices from AWS Elasticsearch Domain into  CSV files.

I appreciate any advise.

Comment: Thanks @Emma but AWS Elasticsearch doesn't provide x-pack feature so far. I use AWS Elasticsearch instead of Elasticsearch.  I saw elasticsearch input plugin in elastic site but I don't see about aws elasticsearch input plugin. That is why I try to export indices from AWS Elasticsearch Domain into CSV files. But I don't know how to export them though.

Comment: I was looking for this, too, using kibana to do that. According to the answer in https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=301908 , they do not even plan to implement this basic feature.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at https://github.com/taraslayshchuk/es2csv.

You could do something like

```
es2csv -u https://your-aws-domain.region.es.amazonaws.com -i your_index_name -o csv_file.csv -r -q '{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}}'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep Kanabar